# Split months into 4 and retrieve the average value per day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, stored-procedures

This is the output of a query on a temporary table created in a complex stored procedure in MySQL :

[image]

The goal now is to have the average duration per day like we have here, but for each week by month

So I want to take every month and divide it **into 4** set of days with the average duration **per day**.
Therefore no matter how many days there are in the month, I will have 4 values for it.

How can I do that ?

*Note : If it is easier I can do it with php, since I will use the data with this language.*

Comment: Don't post your data as a image. We can't work with a image.. Create a ascii data table (formatted text) or make a export and place it on http://www.sqlfiddle.com... Also create a expected output as formatted text.

Comment: So for 28 days of February 2018 you want four result rows (Feb 1-7, Feb 8-14, Feb 15-21, Feb 22-28)? But how then about the other months the days of which are not divisible by 4 without remainder? Would we have to look at hour ranges instead to get chunks of the same duration?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You're right, to make it easier a result like Days1-7, Days8-14, Days15-21, Days22+ would be enough

Comment: Dont expect somebody is going to help you without a better data example and expected results (see mine first comment).. Besides a CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements export in PHPMyAdmin (image looks from PHPMyAdmin) is really eazy to do

Comment: What is the data type of duration? Can it ever be 0? If it can should that value be included in the average or ignored?

Comment: @Nick data type of duration is time, it cannot be 0

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well, apparently some people are more willing to help than others after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a query that groups per day, e.g.:

```
select 
  the_date as day,
  sec_to_time(avg(timestampdiff(second, start_time, end_time))) as duration
from ...
group by the_date;
```

You want days 1-7, 8-14, 15-21, 22-end per month instead. Use `CASE WHEN` to build the groups.

```
select 
  year(the_date) as year,
  month(the_date) as month,
  case 
    when day(the_date) <=  7 then '01-07'
    when day(the_date) <= 14 then '08-14'
    when day(the_date) <= 21 then '15-21'
    else                          '22-end'
  end as day_range,
  sec_to_time(avg(timestampdiff(second, start_time, end_time))) as duration
from ...
group by year, month, day_range
order by year, month, day_range;
```

Comment: It almost work thank you ! The only remaining problem is with this line : sec_to_time(avg(timestampdiff(second, start_time, end_time))) This just do the average, but I need to do the sum for the days(there are multiple start&stop a day) then, the avg for the week. I'm gonna try to do a select from select to solve this

Comment: I added some things to your request to do the avg of sum and it works perfectly, thanks for your help!